Why do you exclude negative numbers from a max path sum algorithm
Here is a correct max path sum algorithm
export function maxPathSum(tree: BinaryTree): number {
  let currMax = -Infinity; 

  const helper = (node: BinaryTree | null): number => {
    if (!node) return 0; 

    const leftVal = Math.max(helper(node.left), 0); 
    const rightVal = Math.max(helper(node.right), 0); 

    currMax = Math.max(leftVal + rightVal + node.value, currMax); 

    return Math.max(leftVal, rightVal) + node.value; 
  }

  helper(tree); 

  return currMax; 
}

I do not understand why I am doing
const leftVal = Math.max(helper(node.left), 0);

Negative numbers are part of the path. To exclude negative numbers would be to get the wrong sum, right? Can someone explain why this logic is correct.

Right. But if they are negative.... is that not part of the sum? I don't understand how you can just casually discard those values.

Like if leftVal is -2, are we literally just cutting that branch off the tree?

@J Seabolt "we literally just cutting that branch off the tree" No, that's not true. Note that, this function runs recursively.

See this picture. In this picture, we have negative numbers. We do not totally cut off the branches, if upper branches makes the left or right sum positive.

If the left branch of the tree is negative, how can I not include that value. I understand it makes the total negative. But again, how am I allowed to just disregard that fact and make it zero.

Note that, in your algorithm, you're "storing" 3 values in each node. leftVal , leftVal  and currMax . If you simply place a print statement, you can simply see that you're not totally removing a branch, if there is a negative number in it.


To exclude negative numbers would be to get the wrong sum, right?

Yes, it would indeed be wrong. But, if you look closely at this code,

const leftVal = Math.max(helper(node.left), 0);

you are not comparing current node value or left/right node value with zero,
you are actually comparing the output of helper for left subtree and right subtree. And then, if you see that the output of left or right subtree is lesser than zero then there is no need to include it in our "max sum" path.

So are you saying that if I determine one branch (let's say left) is negative, I only want to count the current node and the right path. I just say "no two branches for me, the max path only has one branch"
Am I understanding?

Yes, sounds correct, if you'll look at the problem statement you'll find that the maxPath doesn't necessarily need to be leaf to leaf.
